# Add custom functions with optimisations (hence not as UDF)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling with optimisation of my custom functions currently being passed as UDFs. We take transformations configurably via a format like below, and hence cannot explicitly code transformation logic per setting.

```
transforms: [

    {col: "id", expr: """ cast(someCustomFunction(aColumn) as string) """}
    {col: "date", expr: """ date_format(cast(unix_timestamp(someColumn, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") as Timestamp), "yyyyMMdd") """}
  ],
```

I have registered someCustomFunction but I want to optimise this by somehow not creating it as a UDF since Spark blackboxes UDFs. I want to know what is the best approach for achieving this (and then sleeping peacefully):

1. **Extending catalyst optmiser** rules does not help since there is no logical optmisation I can give beforehand.
2. **Column functions** If I use them where/how do i register them (if there is a way to register them at all)
3. **Custom transformations** : Since I pass strings of unknown transformations, how to actually use custom transforms (code will help)
4. **Registering custom functions** beforehand like those in o.a.s.sql.functions package. All the entities in this package are protected or private. Do I have to copy all the spark code to local, add my functions and have my application use my local spark build( I hope not). If not, what is the right way to extend spark-sql to incorporate my functions?
5. Is there some other much easier way that I have missed?

I have been grappling with this for 3 days hence any help (preferably with a code sample) would be a giant Karmic brownie.

Comment: can you elaborate on why udf is bad for you?

Comment: because when I look at the physical plan, all UDFs just show up as UDFs instead of generated codes. This is also mentioned in all docs ... https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs-blackbox.html

Comment: and why is that bad? I don't quite understand what is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: they are not optimised b spark, the link above would give you more insights

Comment: Are you using your udfs for filtering? If not, there is no problem.

Comment: I don't think so, can you explain your point?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179096/discussion-between-shay-and-aasthetic